# KnockOutJS - Combining Mapping plugin with Datasource extension

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

My question involves the KO mapping plugin and [KO datasource extension](https://github.com/CraigCav/ko.datasource).

I'm trying to use Mapping functionality on data retrieved using the Datasource extension.

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhulshof/k6HkW/) on line **26** and **29**.

Line **26** is the one that works, but doesn't give me mapping functionality:

```
this(data);
```

Line **29** is what I'm trying to achieve, but it doesn't work.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
```

I tried so much that I'm starting to think that I'm missing the point of the Mapping plugin. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: if using a Fiddle please try to include enough of the code in the post  for it to still make sense without the Fiddle or you might find your question gets deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found out the issue. The reference to the KO Mapping Plugin was missing. After adding that it seems to work. Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/k6HkW/3/

```
//Add the reference to the Knockout Mapping
```

Thanks.